# How do I make a hash out of many arrays?

Tags: ruby

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

How would I turn that into a hash that looks similar to this:

```
{1=>[6, 11], 2=>[7, 12], 3=>[8, 13], 4=>[9, 14], 5=>[10, 15]]
```

Any help would be appreciated! Trying to do this in Ruby.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far, and any error messages. It will make it easier to help out.

Answer (score 7):

```
foo = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
foo.transpose.map { |x, *y| [x, y] }.to_h
```

Comment: Even more clean and concise than the elegant solution by @tadman. The only downside I see is the need to create an interim transposed array of arrays, but that should be a problem only if the initial array is very large.

Comment: You could avoid the block (not to suggest that would be an improvement) with `foo.first.zip(foo.drop(1).transpose).to_h`.

Answer (score 5):

That's a really strange way of mapping things, but with a clever method signature it's not too hard:

```
def pivot(keys, *values)
  keys.each_with_index.map do |key, i|
    [ key, values.map { |v| v[i] } ]
  end.to_h
end
```

Then you'd call it with a splat:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]

pivot(*a)
# => {1=>[6, 11], 2=>[7, 12], 3=>[8, 13], 4=>[9, 14], 5=>[10, 15]}
```

Comment: @moveson Ruby is great for this sort of thing. If you have a lot of code to solve a simple problem there's usually a better way. Thanks goes to Matz and the Ruby team.

Answer (score 2):

I kind of like `zip`:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
a[0].zip(a[1].zip(a[2])).to_h
```

The downside is that it's hardwired for three subarrays.

This can be generalized with a splat, so

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
a[0].zip(a[1].zip(*a.drop(2))).to_h
```

yields

```
{1=>[6, 11, 16], 2=>[7, 12, 17], 3=>[8, 13, 18], 4=>[9, 14, 19], 5=>[10, 15, 20]}
```

without any additional levels of zipping required.

Comment: You can generalize with a splat: `a[0].zip(a[1].zip(*a.drop(2))).to_h`

Comment: @CarySwoveland By golly, I like it!

Comment: @CarySwoveland I've given the attribution in the edit comments.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your array is stored under the variable name `array` I would go about it like this:

```
hash = {}

array[0].each.with_index do |value, i|
  hash[value] = [array[1][i], array[2][i]]
end
```

Comment: Correct, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

A kind of mixture of pjs and ndn's answers:

```
arr.first.zip(arr[1..-1].transpose).to_h
```

Also very similarly (posted by CarySwoveland) in comments:

```
arr.first.zip(arr.drop(1).transpose).to_h
```